# Bump does not follow my UV map

Tags: uv, bump

Still new to Blender - and this must be a beginners question.

I've made a rough, but usable UV map for my object. The UV checker texture is distributed as expected but my bump is not. Coming from Maya I'm used to bump being distributed as a 2D texture, but it looks like the blender Bump node is using the mesh normals instead. Anyway, I'm been loosing hair over this, can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? (please see image below - I did try to change my bump node to "2D" with no effect)

Thank you in advance!

All the best,
Jeppe

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default an *Image Texture* will use the UV of your object, but a *Noise Texture* won't.

If you don't plug anything into your *Noise Texture*, it will be projected onto your object as if you used the *Texture Coordinate Generated* output, which will take the proportion of your object into account, if it is stretched on Z the noise will be stretched as well:

[image]

Instead use the *Object* output, which will project the texture the same way on all the axis:

[image]

And of course if you want to use the UV unwrap, use the *UV* output, and make sure that you've applied the scale and that the UVs have the correct size.

Comment: Thank you so much moonboots - this makes perfect sense and solved my problem! :)